# ASP.NET MVC File sometimes does not upload

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

have a  asp.net file uploader. It works 95% time but sometimes it throw some exception.

The exception is like that. Please do you know about it. How can I solve it.

Url: https://www.xxxx.com/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx User: 44123 Message: An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x80070001. StackTrace: at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect) at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadEntityCoreSync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFilesCollection() at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Files() at

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve it.

This is happening because, by an external reason, the connection was closed and/or disconnect. **You can only catch it to show an user-friendly error.**

Answer (score 1):

When a ASP.NET error in server ocurred, the application pool end. Check the event viewer on server to discard a possible error of ASP.net.